# How to load Cython compiled .so file on both Mac OS X and Linux?

Tags: python, linux, macos, cython

I compiled a `module.pyx` file to `module.so` under Mac OS X, and now I can use it with:

`from module import method1`

However, the same `.so` file won't work on Linux, I have to compile a new `module.so` under Linux.

So the problem is, how can I write a cross platform(Mac and Linux) module with Cython?

Answer (score 5):

You can't. You'll have to compile a different library for each platform you need to support.

Comment: ... that is, the module _source_ can be cross platform, it just has to be _compiled_ for each platform.

Comment: If so, how can I write a single `export_module.py` to expose a universal interface for both platform?